# Binding to model property not working

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, caliburn.micro

I need to bind the value of a property of a domain model (which gets loaded into a view model) to the content of a control on my shell view, however it isn't working at all (Content stays blank). How can I fix this? Does the domain model need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged too?

#### ShellViewModel

```
public class ShellViewModel : Conductor<ProjectViewModel>.Collection.OneActive, IShell
{

    public ShellViewModel() {
        ActivateItem(new ProjectViewModel(new Project { ProjectName = "Test" }));
    }

}
```

#### ShellView (tab control)

```
<TabControl x:Name="Items">
        <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ActiveItem.Project.ProjectName}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

#### ProjectViewModel

```
public class ProjectViewModel : Screen
{

    private Project _project;

    public Project Project
    {
        get { return _project; }
        private set
        {
            _project = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => _project);
        }
    }

    public ProjectViewModel(Project project)
    {
        Project = project;
    }
```

#### Project

```
public class Project
{

    public string ProjectName { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: do you have a property "ActivateItem" in your ShellViewModel ??

Comment: or even better yet do you have a collection named Items ?

Comment: @TYY, Why `Items`? It's just the name of the TabControl?

Comment: He is using caliburn, so usually you name controls so that Caliburn looks into your viewmodel and finds the appropriate object to bind to. If you notice the OP did not specify any bindings to the TabControl (so how is he creating TabItems this is why I asked the question).

Comment: If you put a breakpoint somewhere and check out your `TabControl.DataContext`, aka `Items.DataContext` using your code sample, what type of collection does it resolve to? It should be a collection of items where each item has the property `ActiveItem.Project.ProjectName`, so you can call something like `Collection[x].ActiveItem.Project.ProjectName`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you wanna use binding then the object of the property you bind to have to implement INotifyPropertyChanged. otherwise you just see the initial value. so yes the easy way would be that your domain model implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

```
   <TextBlock Text="{Binding ActiveItem.Project.ProjectName}" />
```

with this line wpf dont care about OnPropertyChanged("Project") because its bound to ProjectName.

Answer (score 0):

Don't have your Conductor.Collection be of type ProjectViewModel make it Screen or IScreen since ProjectViewModel inherits Screen that is the best choice.  Once that is done you do an collection call in the Constructor of the ShellViewModel.

**shellviewmodel** will look like this.

```
public ShellViewModel(/*IEnumerable<Screen> screens*/){  // Not Necessary 

     //automatically finds what is in the IoC Container 
     //(MEF, SimpleContainer, AutoFac, StructureMap etc... 
     //Assuming your using one...

     //this.Items.AddRange(screens);
      this.Items.Add(new ProjectViewModel(new Project(){ ProjectName = "Test";}));   
}
protected override OnInitialize(){

}
```

**Template**

```
<TabControl x:Name="Items">
    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <StackPanel>
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName}" />
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding Project.ProjectName}" /> 
          </StackPanel>                     
        </DataTemplate>
 </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
```

The reason I do `DisplayName` it is already in Screen's class object as a property...  This way you don't have to do much extra work, coding out your ViewModels.

```
public class ProjectViewModel : Screen{
  private Project _project;
  public ProjectViewModel(Project project){

    DisplayName = "Test" ;

    Project = project;
  }  
  public Project Project{
       get{ return _project;}
       private set{
           _project = value;
           NotifyOfPropertyChange();
       }
    }
 }
```

On the Model objects that you want to show would inherit `PropertyChangedBase`

On the ViewModels they will inherit either PropertyChangedBased, Screen, or even Conductor (for example).  All having different needs to suit what it is your trying to do.

Another thing to look at is the IoC container that is in the project well actually there are 2 of them.  1 SimpleContainer 2 MEF, most if not all of the samples use MEF.

Comment: My conductor collection is of the specific type ProjectViewModel because first, this is the only type of view models I need to display and second, that way I gain intellisense support for the bindings on the ShellViewModel because that way, ShellViewModel knowns ProjectViewModel. Also, I'm not sure what you are trying to tell me because apart from your comment about the ProjectViewModel conductor, my code is exactly the same. My only problem is that {Binding Project.ProjectName} does not bind anything (ProjectName won't show in TabItem header, even if it's set)..

Comment: Here is an example app that I think you have setup on your side compare the 2 and tell me how your differs from mine? https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=C9472B51C27DC8FE!84921

Comment: Do you have a ProjectView.xaml usercontrol? Sample above uses CM 2.0